# What happens when I try to create an object using its empty default constructor but while adding brackets in ANSI C++?

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a class called "Complex" which is intended to represent complex numbers. I have defined an empty default constructor for the class that only prints a message to the screen.
When I try to create an object of the class in the main function as follows:

```
Complex c1();
```

The compiler(I am using BorlandC) doesn't give a syntax error but it doesn't create the object. How does the compiler interpret this line?

Comment: It is a function declaration, not an object construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write this:

```
int foo();
```

…it declares a function called `foo` that returns an `int`.

When you write this:

```
Complex c1();
```

…it declares a function called `c1` that returns a `Complex`.

**Lose the `()`.**

Contrary to popular belief, this is not quite "the most vexing parse", but it is close.

Comment: As a curious follow-up question can you mention what you consider as "the most vexing parse"? :)

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy `Complex c1(Complex(arg))` also declares a function. [Read more on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: *Second most* vexing parse?